# Problemas con conexion de base de datos desde una jar

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas tardes apenas estoy empezando a convertir en ejecutable mis proyectos, lo que pasa que cuando uso mi proyecto en el IDE funciona sin problemas pero a la hora de exportarlo y ejecutarlo en otra pc y al ntentar acceder por un login que usa bd marca el error de: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, puse el .jar que use en mi programa de mysql a la carpeta lib de tomcat pero tampoco asi funciona, mi codigo de mi conexion es:

```
public class Conexion {
private static Connection cnx = null;
public static Connection conectar() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    if(cnx==null){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cnx=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebalabo","root","");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            throw new SQLException(ex);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            throw new ClassCastException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return cnx;
}
public static void cerrar() throws SQLException{
    if(cnx!=null){
        cnx.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tal vez es la ubicación del archivo .jar ya que al exportar el proyecto por lo general no es el mismo que usas en el IDE. Intenta probando si al agregar la libreria a lado del ejecutable funciona o de otro modo también intenta creando una carpeta llamada lib en donde esta tu ejecutable y agrega la libreria de MySQL en esa carpeta y mira si funciona.

Comment: hola Alex el error que me sale solo dice esto: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Hola, explicanos como realizas el ejecutable, es decir que si utilizas algún programa, solo generas una .jar o realizas algún paso extra; y si puedes adjunta una captura en donde se muestre donde esta agregada la libreria antes de hacer el ejecutable.

Comment: claro, realizo el ejecutable desde netbeans en la pestaña de Run en la opcion de Clean and Build Project

Comment: Intenta agregar la libreria de MySQL a lado del ejecutable y mira si funciona, también intenta creando una carpeta llamada lib a lado del ejecutable y pon la libreria en esa carpeta.

Comment: lo intenté y nada

Answer (score 0):

Hola habboerwin no estoy seguro si te puede funcionar un Jar que usa otros jar internos por ejemplo:(librerías de conexión), te recomiendo que uses algun programa para crear el instalador de tu aplicación.
En lo personal yo uso "Advance Installer" para crear instalador de mis programas java es muy bueno.

En Advance Installer durante la creación del instalador tiene un sección que es para agregar todas esas librerías externas (*.jar) ya sea de conexión o look and feel etc.

Comment: Lo use y el error se fue pero al generar reportes como esos reportes tienen una foto me sale que no se encuentra cuando el archivo si se encuentra